# MYSQL query to find all duplicated record with specified column groupings

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds all the emails sent for email campaigns:

```
ID | campaign_id | date_sent | date_delivered | email | status
```

`Status` holds delivery information, `DELIVERED` or `UNDELIVERED`. I want to find all email addresses that their status is `UNDELIVERED` for the last five campaigns.

For example, `email@address.com` used to be ok and received all campaigns, but now the email address does not exist and the last 5 campaigns status is `UNDELIVERED`.

So far I am doing:

```
SELECT *, count(id) as occ FROM message_details WHERE status='FAILED' GROUP BY email
```

But this is showing the total of undelivered for every address and not the last 5.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you question completely but why not use LIMIT?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit tricky to read. Basically, what it is trying to do is to get top 5 message_details for each email then select those that have number of failed times equal to 5.

Haven't got time to test this code though.

```
SELECT *, count(thirdTable.id) as failTimes FROM
(SELECT rs.id, rs.Status, rs.email
    FROM (
        SELECT *, Rank() 
          over (Partition BY Section
                ORDER BY RankCriteria DESC ) AS Rank
        FROM message_details 
        ) rs WHERE Rank <= 5 ) as thirdTable
Where thirdTable.status = 'FAILED' GROUP BY thirdTable.email HAVING failTimes = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT TOP 5 CampID,COUNT(id) Occ FROM dbo.message_details
WHERE Status    = 'FAILED'
GROUP BY CampID
ORDER BY CampID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group), I've tried some answer to that post. What you want to fetch is  last 5 fail sent campaign of all emails, so it seems that your sql `SELECT *, count(id) as occ FROM message_details WHERE status='FAILED' GROUP BY email` can not make it actually.

Assume your data like this:

```
message_details
---
| ID | campaign_id | date_sent | date_delivered | email | status | 
| 1 | 1 | 2016-04-21 | null | aaa@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 2 | 2 | 2016-04-22 | null | aaa@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 3 | 3 | 2016-04-23 | null | aaa@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 4 | 4 | 2016-04-24 | null | aaa@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 5 | 5 | 2016-04-25 | null | aaa@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 6 | 6 | 2016-04-26 | null | aaa@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 7 | 1 | 2016-04-21 | null | ddd@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 8 | 2 | 2016-04-22 | null | ddd@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 9 | 3 | 2016-04-23 | null | ddd@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 10 | 4 | 2016-04-24 | null | ddd@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 11 | 5 | 2016-04-25 | null | ddd@aaa.aaa | FAILED | 
| 12 | 6 | 2016-04-26 | null | ddd@aaa.aaa | FAILED |
```

Then run this sql,

```
SELECT t1.email, t1.campaign_id
FROM message_details t1
LEFT JOIN message_details t2 ON t1.email = t2.email AND t1.date_sent <= t2.date_sent
WHERE t1.status='FAILED'
GROUP BY t1.email, t1.campaign_id, t1.date_sent
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5
```

I got below result set,

```
| email | campaign_id | 
| aaa@aaa.aaa | 2 | 
| aaa@aaa.aaa | 3 | 
| aaa@aaa.aaa | 4 | 
| aaa@aaa.aaa | 5 | 
| aaa@aaa.aaa | 6 | 
| ddd@aaa.aaa | 2 | 
| ddd@aaa.aaa | 3 | 
| ddd@aaa.aaa | 4 | 
| ddd@aaa.aaa | 5 | 
| ddd@aaa.aaa | 6 |
```

I don't know if this works for you, but you can take a look on that link above. And if you've got some solution for your post, share it to me will be appreciated.